# I want to update content in ios (Swift4) from url every less than second

Tags: ios, swift4

> I am making a cricket app. I want to update the labels in ios from url every time server sends me the json file. How should i write the url code.

---

```
import UIKit
import Foundation



struct jsonScore : Decodable  {
let comment : String
let venuDetails : String
let valueToDisplay : String
let bowlingTeam : String
let battingTeam : String

let overs : Double
let targetScore : Int
let wickets : Int
let score : Int








let striker : striker
 let nonStriker : nonStriker
 let strikerBowler : strikerBowler


}

struct striker : Decodable{

let name: String
let runs: String
let balls: String
let fours: String
let sixes: String

}

struct nonStriker : Decodable{

let name: String
let runs: String
let balls: String
let fours: String
let sixes: String

}


struct strikerBowler : Decodable{
    let name : String
    let overs : String
    let maidens : String
    var runs : String
    let wickets : String
}



class ViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var Comment: UITextView!
@IBOutlet weak var VenuDetails: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var ValueToDisplay: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var battingTeam: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var bowlingTeam: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var wickets: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var overs: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var score: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var striker: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var strikerRun: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var nonStriker: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var nonStrikerRun: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var strikerBowlerName: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var strikerBowlerOver: UILabel!


var timer = Timer()
// start the timer
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.5, target: self, selector: #selector(getUpdatedData), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}
@objc func getUpdatedData() {
let jsonUrlString = "url from server"
    
    guard let url = URL(string : jsonUrlString ) else
    { return }
    
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, err) in
       guard let data = data else { return }
            //get your updated data here and update it into the UI.
       
        do {
            
            let jsonscore = try JSONDecoder().decode(jsonScore.self, from: data)
            
            self.VenuDetails.text = jsonscore.venuDetails
            self.Comment.text = jsonscore.comment
            self.bowlingTeam.text = jsonscore.bowlingTeam
            self.battingTeam.text = jsonscore.battingTeam
            self.ValueToDisplay.text = jsonscore.valueToDisplay
            self.wickets.text = String(jsonscore.wickets)
            self.overs.text = String(jsonscore.overs)
           
            self.score.text = String(jsonscore.score)
            self.striker.text = jsonscore.striker.name + "*"
            self.strikerRun.text = jsonscore.striker.runs

            self.nonStriker.text = jsonscore.nonStriker.name
            self.nonStrikerRun.text = jsonscore.nonStriker.runs

            self.strikerBowlerName.text = jsonscore.strikerBowler.name
            self.strikerBowlerOver.text = jsonscore.strikerBowler.overs

            print(jsonscore)
           
        }catch let jsonErr{
            print("Error serializing json:", jsonErr)
        }
        
    }.resume()
    
}





}
```

---

> now i want to add async and cachebuster so that as soon as json is fetched from server it gets updated in the app. I used timer func as suggested by daljeet. But the labels in app are not updating after first updation. I want to update the app label as soon as server send the json file.
>
> Please help me writing the code

Comment: What have you tried up to this point? Please see [how to write a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Nobody to help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Timer for it:

var timer = Timer()
    timer.invalidate() // just in case this button is tapped multiple times

```
        // start the timer
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.5, target: self, selector: #selector(getUpdatedData), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

And

```
func getUpdatedData() {
            //get your updated data here and update it into the UI.
    }
```

Comment: Used it in the code with reduced time interval to meet the api from cricbuzz but after sometime it doesnt update the app.
Do i need to use some cache or anything else. Please suggest.

Comment: If you did above answer you can mark it right and what do you mean by it doesnt update the app. Please explain so i can help you. If you have another problem statement you can ask in another question.

Comment: We have a server side control panel from which operator updates the score using keystroke. Every time he presses the key to update score the server side creates a josn file. I want to update the iOS label as soon as key is pressed and json file is passed.

Comment: Do you get the data by Rest API or by push notification. How you are managing it?

Comment: I get data from Rest API.